# Record link analysis / validation of records (URL checks) don't use web proxy configuration

Tags: geonetwork

If we try to analyze the record links, geonetwork server ignore the webproxy configuration and try to connect on direct way.

The proxy is set in the admin settings and also with JVM parameters.

For example Harvesting is working over proxy, it only fail at URL checks.

We also tried to set a global system proxy on our Red Hat system but nothing worked.

geonetwork-version: 3.10.1

Comment: Was your problem solved by setting the JVM command line options for proxy settings, like suggested below by juanluisrp? in that case could you report the command line options you used.

Answer (score 1):

Using the config UI is the right way of setting the proxy in GeoNetwork. Setting it through JVM command line options also should work. If it isn't working I'd suggest you to open a bug report in GeoNetwork [Github](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues) describing the problem so the developers can fix it.